# Rails Response Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a rails endpoint that is responding very slow to requests. It returns a json list with a size of up to 600kb. The logs states `Completed 200 OK in 1289ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 32.9ms)` however the request takes nearly 6 seconds (!) in the browser to complete also stated in the Header `X-Runtime:6.537820`.

We tried to debug it with newrelic, but the time musst spend somewhere in the middleware? How can we debug this? Rails is currently running local with WEBrick in development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `rack-mini-profiler` gem. It will give you detailed breakdown on how much time each operation takes. I have used this gem to identify a couple of issues that caused high render time.

https://github.com/miniprofiler/rack-mini-profiler

Comment: Thanks, that is working quite well for me especially with the `flamegraph` gem

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing the Rails Panel extension in Chrome and its attendant gem meta_request to your gem file.

[Rails Panel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/railspanel/gjpfobpafnhjhbajcjgccbbdofdckggg?hl=en-US)

I've found this to be a very helpful gem. As you will see when you read the Rails Panel extension page in the Chrome Web Store, it does a good job of breaking down what happens during the life cycle of your Rails request. Good time breakdowns, view-by-view times for rending, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the panel however it shows a total of 1270ms. I still don`t know where i loose those 6.9 secs

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you manually add up the view times in the Rails Panel, does it still leave that 6 seconds missing? The reason I ask is that I just added up my view times and it included, for that request anyway, the "other" times as well.

Comment: yes - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6dlurn9h13bpyf/Bildschirmfoto%202014-03-13%20um%2018.38.50.png